# Error with cases enviroment: missing $ inserted

Tags: cases

Hey there I have a problem with the cases enviroment inside an equation i'm getting the error missing $ inserted but i don't know why.
I already searched and found that there are now blank lines inside a equation allowed but i'm not sure where they should be in my case.
Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{amsbook}
%Sprache
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Zeichensatz
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%PDF Integrierung
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%Formatierung
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%Schriftart
\usepackage{helvet}
%Mathepackages
\usepackage{amsfonts,amstext,amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
%Algorithmen
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic,program}
%diverses
\usepackage{enumerate}
%Theoreme und Gleichungen
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{prop}{Satz}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithmus}
%Titelseite festlegen
\author{name\\
}
\title{Bachelorarbeit}
%Beginn der Seminarbeit
\begin{document}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{lemma}
Die Supremumsnorm den k-ten Potenz von M ist gegeben durch
\begin{equation*}
\|M^k\| = \begin{cases}
\binom{N-1}{k} &  | \beta | = 1,\\
\frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}} \frac{z^{N-1}-1}{z-1} z =|\beta| & 7 | \beta | \neq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

I would be very glad if you could help me,  i have another equation where it works just fine.
Naro

Comment: Welcome, adding a document structure around your code snippet (`\documentclass` etc.) i don't see any problem. It works just fine.

Comment: Thats really strange if i do that i get the same error. I'm using TexMaker if thats any help

Comment: Please show the log file of that really small example.

Comment: I hope that helps http://textuploader.com/58lna Thank you

Comment: I've added my header. Sorry if it takes a bit long I'm new to this

Comment: There is some problem with the pipes `|` (see a bunch of answers below...)

Comment: you say in your question "there are now blank lines ..."; i read this as "no blank lines", but it is possible that there *are* blank lines that aren't shown in the example.  that would certainly result in the error you see.  if you *do* really have any blank lines within the scope of math, *remove them*.

Answer (score 5):

The `program` package defines `|` as an active character for its usage in the `program` environment and this causes the problem you have. However, the package provides an adjustment in case you want to use `|` in math mode.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{amsbook}

\usepackage{program}

\normalbaroutside % <----- ADDED

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\|M^k\| = \begin{cases}
\binom{N-1}{k} &  | \beta | = 1,\\
\frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}} \frac{z^{N-1}-1}{z-1} z =|\beta| & | \beta | \neq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

However, it would be much better with

```
\lVert M^k\rVert
```

and

```
\lvert\beta\rvert
```

avoiding the unadorned `|` that is overloaded.

---

A good alternative to using `\lVert`–`\rVert` and `\lvert`–`\rvert` is with `mathtools` that also provides a `dcases` environment. Here's an example with both input and output. Note that in your text you don't have `k` and `M` in math mode, which is wrong.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{program}

\normalbaroutside % it should be standard

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

Die Supremumsnorm den $k$-ten Potenz von $M$ ist gegeben durch
\begin{equation*}
\norm{M^k} = \begin{dcases}
\binom{N-1}{k} &  \abs{\beta} = 1,\\
\frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}} \frac{z^{N-1}-1}{z-1} z =\abs{\beta} &
   \abs{\beta} \neq 1
\end{dcases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Package `program` is destroying your parade. `|` isn't so good to use anyway, substitute it with proper macros from package `physics` (alternativesavailable).

[image: naroCases]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{lemma}
    Die Supremumsnorm den k-ten Potenz von M ist gegeben durch
    \begin{equation*}
        \norm{M^k} = \begin{cases}
            \binom{N-1}{k} &  \abs{\beta} = 1,\\
            \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}} \frac{z^{N-1}-1}{z-1} z =\abs{\beta} & 7 \abs{\beta} \neq 1
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright thank you! That helps i'm using program for some pseudocode so i will look for an alternative. If I remove it, it works i will see if i can find another package for my pseudo code.

Comment: @Naro The code works fine with pacage `program`. Test it. But you have to look for an alternative for producing absolutes and norms. Thankfully, package `physics` gives you handy commands. And the result is scalable. Compare the norm M^k in my anser with the screenshot of the other.

Comment: Well, `program` and `physics` are aimed to very different targets. I'd not recommend `physics`, though, for a math document.

Comment: @egreg `physics` is the one i like most. `skmath` provides similar macros if i recall correctly. Edit: Checked, exactly the same macro names for this case.

Comment: @Johannes_B I find `physics` trying to do too much; and `skmath` is not as bad as `commath`, but…

Comment: @egreg I guess we agree with the fact, that `lvert` and friends are better than using a pipe symbol. Both mentioned packages use that internally. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles to

[image]

when wrapped as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{lemma}
Die Supremumsnorm den k-ten Potenz von M ist gegeben durch
\begin{equation*}
\|M^k\| =
\begin{cases}
  \binom{N-1}{k} &  | \beta | = 1,\\
  \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}} \frac{z^{N-1}-1}{z-1} z =|\beta| & 7 | \beta | \neq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

To generate the image I used http://sciencesoft.at/latex/?lang=en

Comment: The OP has already supplied a log showing that the error is produced, so this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I must have written this at the same time that he edited. The other answers are more to the point.